# Intellij build artifact - runnable jar UTF-8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build, artifact

I builded a project that reads a csv file (saved as csv UTF-8).
in my project i read every line of that csv file.
The output of every line is displayed in a log file.

Now when i run my project in intellij and i look into the log file all the lines are readable.
But when i build an artifact from my project and then run that jar some symbols that are in the csv are replaced by a '?' symbol ..

i looked into the settings of my project under file encoding and there is everything UTF-8 also.

I have no clue how that is possible ..
Can anyone help me out ? Thx !

Comment: Does it help if you run it with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` VM option from the command line jar?

Comment: Can you give me an example of the full line that i must type in cmd ?

Comment: `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar yourapp.jar param1 param2`

Comment: Yes it works ! many many thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the encoding when running the app from the command line like this:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar yourapp.jar param1 param2
```

Or change your app code that reads/writes files to explicitly force the correct encoding.

Answer (score 0):

When I specify -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, I need to put this encoding option between two " however it doesn't work and an error is returned. Maybe it will help somebody with the same problem as me.

```
java "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" -jar app.jar
```